# Prevent Enterprise library logging from adding default values to log

Tags: logging, enterprise-library-5

I am trying to customize Enterprise library logging by adding a formatter inside the app.config file. The problem is that the logging API dumps additional information along with the item I specified in the formatter.

Here is the App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="LoggingBlock" tracingEnabled="true"
    defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="RollingFile" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="DataLog.log" formatter="SimpleFormatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
        rollInterval="Day" rollSizeKB="10000" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;" name="SimpleFormatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="RollingFile" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings" />
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

I expected it to append only one line to the log file:

> Message: Sample log text

but it adds the following:

> Message: There is no explicit mapping for the categories 'Info'. The
>   log entry was:   Timestamp: 31/10/2013 8:59:01 AM
>
> Message: Sample log text
>
> Category: Info
>
> Priority: 2
>
> EventId: 1
>
> Severity: Information
>
> Title:
>
> Machine: SERVER1
>
> App Domain: SAMPLE.exe
>
> ProcessId: 1104
>
> Process Name:
>
> Thread Name:
>
> Win32 ThreadId:9644
>
> Extended Properties:

How do I get rid of the additional lines?

The API used is:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(message, category, priority)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that you can do so by overriding the formatter type in the app.config file like so:

```
<add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="[{timestamp(local)}] {category},{machine},{message}"
        name="Text Formatter" />
```

The difficulty was in finding the template keywords for the data I was interested in adding to the log.